# How to target a class based on the elements name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, name-attribute

How do I target a class based on its name:

```
<input type="submit" name="addtocart" class="addtocart-button" value="Add to Cart" title="Add to Cart">
```

```js
$("[name="addtocart]").removeClass('addtocart-button');
```

This is what I thought how to do it, but doesnt work.

Comment: Try `$("[name=addtocart]").removeClass('addtocart-button');`. Remove `"` before `addtocart`.

Comment: You can give the input an id, and select it by id using jQuery.

Comment: thank you, i didnt see the `"` thank you for the help

Comment: See your given code closely. @user2513528

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
$("input[name=addtocart]").removeClass('addtocart-button');
```

It should work.